# Command to Strikeout text and citation?

Tags: formatting, strikeout

I am making major edits (a hack and slash) to a big document, want to do a word count on what's there (hence texcount), and, while I'm editing and we are reviewing, I want to retain what I'm removing in situ in strikeout text.

The text has citations so in places these will need strikeouts also and I would like to be able to easily ultimately remove this text from the final document by a simple change of my commands and if the text is ignored I want to ignore any citations in the section so LaTeX does not look up by `.bib` files and add the citation to the `bibliography`. At the moment I am using `makeboxes` to try and format the strikeout but I am not getting the results I expect.

I am new to `LaTeX` so please excuse my poor code. There is more explanation in the code below. Thanks

```
%TC: macro \cmd [1]

\documentclass[]{article}
\immediate\write18{texcount.pl -total \jobname.tex -out=\jobname.sum}

\newcommand{\cmt}[1]{}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand\wordcount{\verbatiminput{\jobname.sum}}


% This is my command. I want to strike out, 
\newcommand{\strikeit}[1]
{
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{\sout{#1}}
}



\begin{document}
The first thing I want is to have this word count which ignores the words contained in the \textbackslash cmd macro
\wordcount

I want to be able to strike out text \sout{like this} and also be able to \sout{strikeout citations like this : \mbox{\cite{CA,HB98}}} and still have evertthing in situ but do all of this from a command that I can later edit to remove the edits from my pdf if they are all approved rather than manually editing the tex file twice.

Problem 1: This should be the width of the page and be in situ, but it's not \strikeit{\blindtext}

How do I wrap the text to the page (or text) width?

Problem 2: The next issue I am having is to do with citations.
\strikeit{
    \cite{CA,HB98} 
}

As you can see, the first citation is there, but the second is missing.
Also I'm getting the error \textit{Undefined Control Sequence. \}}

And Problem 3: When the edits are accepted I want to ultimatly be able to generate a PDF that will ignore these sections of text by changing my command \textit{\textbackslash strikeit} to

\textit{\textbackslash newcommand{\textbackslash strikeit}[1]{}}

but will also not process the citations if they are inside that command.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

    \bibitem{HB98} Huynen, M.~A. and Bork, P. 1998. Measuring genome evolution. {\em
        Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences USA}
    95:5849--5856.
    \bibitem{CA} Caprara, A. 1997. Sorting by reversals is difficult. In: {\em
        Proceedings of the First Annual International Conference on Computational
        Molecular Biology (RECOMB 97),} New York: ACM.  pp. 75-83.
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can write `\verb+\newcommand...+` if you want to show literal (La)TeX code in your document, instead of `\textbackslash` etc.

Comment: `\mbox{\cite{...}}` will work.

Comment: Maybe a versioning system (subversion, git) better suits your needs here? This looks like you try to recreate 'track changes' in MS Word / LibreOffice etc. which is not something that can be easily done in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **no** solution for the text wrapping in case of `strikeout`, but it removes the problem with `\sout` and `\cite` etc.

I've defined a `\ifcorrectingmode` switch and set it to true using `\correctingmodetrue`.

While this is active, `\strikeit` will show the effect of `\sout`. In the final run, just say `\correctingmodefalse` and `\strikeit` does nothing.

The `\cite` command isn't expandable, that's why `\sout` does not work, but it's possible to put `\cite` in box which is then stroke out.

```
%TC:macro \cmt [ignore]

\documentclass[]{article}
\immediate\write18{texcount -total \jobname.tex -out=\jobname.sum}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\newcommand{\cmt}[1]{}



\newcommand\wordcount{\verbatiminput{\jobname.sum}}

\newif\ifcorrectingmode
\correctingmodetrue

\LetLtxMacro\origcite\cite

% This is my command. I want to strike out, 
\newcommand{\strikeit}[1]{%
  \ifcorrectingmode
  \mbox{\sout{#1}}%
%  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{\sout{#1}}%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{%
  \ifcorrectingmode
  \mbox{\origcite[#1]{#2}}%
  \else
  \origcite[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
The first thing I want is to have this word count which ignores the words contained in the \textbackslash cmd macro
\wordcount

I want to be able to strike out text \sout{like this} and also be able to \sout{strikeout citations like this : \mbox{\cite{CA,HB98}}} and still have evertthing in situ but do all of this from a command that I can later edit to remove the edits from my pdf if they are all approved rather than manually editing the tex file twice.

Problem 1: This should be the width of the page and be in situ, but it's not \strikeit{\blindtext}

How do I wrap the text to the page (or text) width?

Problem 2: The next issue I am having is to do with citations.
\strikeit{%
  \cite{CA,HB98}
}

As you can see, the first citation is there, but the second is missing.
Also I'm getting the error \textit{Undefined Control Sequence. \}}

And Problem 3: When the edits are accepted I want to ultimatly be able to generate a PDF that will ignore these sections of text by changing my command 
\verb+\strikeit+ to

\verb+\newcommand{\strikeit}[1]{}+

but will also not process the citations if they are inside that command.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

    \bibitem{HB98} Huynen, M.~A. and Bork, P. 1998. Measuring genome evolution. {\em
        Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences USA}
    95:5849--5856.
    \bibitem{CA} Caprara, A. 1997. Sorting by reversals is difficult. In: {\em
        Proceedings of the First Annual International Conference on Computational
        Molecular Biology (RECOMB 97),} New York: ACM.  pp. 75-83.
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```